# How do I check an array for patterns?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I return an array of indexes in contents that match the pattern.

```
var contents = ["Dog is big","Cat is small","Horse is huge"]

(contents,"og") //returns [0,2]
(contents,"at") //returns [1]
(contents,"..") //etc
```

So, "o" and "g" are both in 0 and 2 but not in 1.

note: the letters don't have to be in that order.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: What will happen when you try to find `at` in  `["big is bat","Cat is small"]`. Both of them contain `at`

Comment: @user2181397 - the OP would expect `[0,1]` as both items contain the desired letters at least once.

Comment: It's not searching for a pattern though.  "og" is only contained in the first item.  What have you tried?  Show us your code.

Comment: i dont have any code because im literally stuck with where to even start. Ive looked at stuff like indexOf() but that works with 1 thing to my understanding.

Comment: @ForeverStuck - your question is quite trivial. Use `indexOf` inside a loop, or `map` and return the truthy indexes.

Comment: Let me give you a tip. Somewhere in you code you should use `Array.prototype.some()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) methods.

```js
var contents = ["Dog is big", "Cat is small", "Horse is huge"]

console.log(get(contents, "og")); 
console.log(get(contents, "at")); 
console.log(get(contents, "..")); 

function get(arr, str) {
  // array for storing result
  var res = [];
  // iterate over string array
  arr.forEach(function(v, i) {
    // split string into individual character and 
    // check for each for match 
    // if all elements matched push the element
    if (str.split('').every(function(v1) {
      return v.indexOf(v1) > -1;
    }))
      res.push(i);
  });
  return res;
}
```

Comment: thank you for helping me to answer my question. Plus, thanks a lot for explaining it. Im trying to learn javascript and the quotations really help me with this. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Array.prototype.every` to filter out the indices which matches your criteria - see demo below:

```js
var contents = ["Dog is big","Cat is small","Horse is huge"];

function filter(filter) {
  var f = filter.split('');
  return contents.reduce(function(p,c,i){
    f.every(e=>~c.indexOf(e)) && p.push(i);
    return p;
  },[]);
}

console.log(filter("og"));
console.log(filter("at"));
```

Comment: thank you for your time in helping me to work this out. Its really appreciated